# Why would relatives in Massachusetts cross New Hampshire border to be married?

Tags: 20th-century, marriage-records, marriage-practices, massachusetts, new-hampshire

I have been doing some genealogical research, and have stumbled across an unusual scenario. Several relatives, between 1930 and 1960, traveled from Lawrence, MA to Windham, NH to be married. As far as I know, there is no connection between the relatives and anyone in Windham, or even the town itself. There is nothing to suggest there was any haste in getting married, or any impediment in Massachusetts law. Any idea why several couples with no connection to Windham would travel there to be married?

Comment: I just stumbled upon this, 5 years later! This makes sense. I have found several relatives who lived from Boston, all the way up to the New Hampshire border, that got married in New Hampshire in the late 1930's. I'm guessing Massachusetts had some kind of waiting law. Now to see if I can verify that!

Comment: I recall that some Van Deusen's in western Massachussets were married in New York. I believe it was because of a waiting law. I read this in a history or genealogy book, unfortunately, I don't remember where.

Comment: My ancestor, Andrew Van Deusen, native of Mass, married 1815 in NY.  *... crossed the border to avoid being published*. This according to an article in the Clinton County Trails [Michican], Genealogists of the Clinton County Historical Society, December 2000.

Answer (score 3):

In the comments on the post [Have you searched and searched for the marriage without finding it?](http://www.arleneeakle.com/wordpress/2007/02/19/have-you-searched-and-searched-for-the-marriage-without-finding-it/) by Arlene on *Arlene Eakle's Genealogy Blog*, a comment posted on February 14, 2012 at 6:05 pm by annamadori says:

> I helped process and index many of the marriage records for
>   Fredericksburg, Virginia. We were amazed at the time that the number
>   of marriages from about 1938 until mid 1941 was so much greater than
>   in previous years. Several years after the index was completed we
>   found newspaper articles from the Free Lance Star for July 31 and
>   August 1, 1941 that solved the mystery. In 1938 laws took effect in
>   Maryland and other eastern states requiring a waiting period before
>   marriage. On Aug 1, 1941 a similar law took effect in Virginia. People
>   came from up and down the eastern US and as far west as Ohio.

You've ruled out differences in state law as a motive for your relatives' marriages, but it would still be interesting to know if there is a spike in marriage records for Windham during this time period.  Knowing (and being able to cite) the laws for each state during the time period could back up your assertion that there was no impediment for the marriages to take place in Massachusetts.

I asked for directions between the two towns on Google Maps and got this result:

[image]

Another possibility is that the nearby Canobie Lake had a venue which became popular for destination weddings.  If you can find ephemera from the period or period newspapers or magazines, you might be able to find some clues.

Answer (score -2):

As someone from Massachusetts, that got married in New Hampshire it might not be laws or anything like that. It might be a spot that they found and liked, like I had. The fact that it is really easy to drive anywhere in NH from MA in a matter of hours is a factor as well.

In fact, my cousin from MA is getting married at [Searles Castle](http://www.searlescastle.com) in Windham in about 2 weeks. It is very likely this is the where this marriage took place as well.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.

Comment: Searles Castle was a private home until 1952. Since then it was used as a novitiate for young women entering the Sisters of Mercy. Doubt there were marriages taking place there until 2019.